# Next.js 13 with next-auth, having trouble with signOut. "No HTTP methods exported"

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I'm trying to use the `signOut` method from `next-auth/react`.

This code was previously working

```
"use client"
import { signIn, signOut, } from "next-auth/react";
<button onClick={() => signOut()}>Logout</button>
```

But, I've been making lots of changes to my app, and now I can't log out!

In the server terminal, it says:

`No HTTP methods exported in '/Users/.../app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.`

Here's the Chrome console:

[image]

And finally, my auth code:

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions, User } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { db } from "@/lib/prisma";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db as any),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }: { token: any; session: any }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.name = token.name;
        session.user.email = token.email;
        session.user.image = token.picture;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any; user: any }) {
      const dbUser = await db.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          email: token.email,
        },
      });

      if (!dbUser) {
        if (user) {
          token.id = user?.id;
        }
        return token;
      }

      return {
        id: dbUser.id,
        name: dbUser.name,
        email: dbUser.email,
        picture: dbUser.image,
      };
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to add the following code to the end of my `../[...nextauth]/route.ts` file:

```
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I had commented it out somewhere along the way because I wasn't sure what it was accomplishing...

From ChatGPT:

`const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)`

This line of code creates an instance of the NextAuth authentication handler, using the configuration options defined in authOptions.

`export { handler as GET, handler as POST }`

This exports the handler as both GET and POST methods. In Next.js, when a file is inside the pages/api directory, it is treated as an API route. By default, an API route only responds to a specific HTTP method (e.g., GET, POST, etc.). However, by exporting the same handler as both GET and POST, you are saying that this handler should handle both GET and POST requests to this API route.